# Loading package twice with \RequirePackage causes "option clash"

Tags: errors, documentclass-writing, package-options, dependencies

I thought that loading a package twice with the same options cannot lead to option clash, still I get a clash in the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

This is a MnWE, what I really want to achieve is to create two dependent classes like this:

**myclass.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2012/05/24 v1.0 My Class]

\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}

\endinput
```

**anotherclass.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{anotherclass}[2012/05/24 v1.0 Another Class]

\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}

% I need to use some features of `kvoptions` here

\LoadClass{myclass}

\endinput
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{anotherclass}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

**Version information**

- It works properly with *LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>* (TeXLive installed 2009)
- It does not work with *LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>* (TeXLive installed 2012)

Comment: your MWE works for me - no clash

Comment: It works in my old TeXlive2009. But it does not work with a TeXlive that I installed 2 days ago from the web...

Comment: strange ... it does here ...
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
...
So looks like it also worked with TL2011 but not with the current version from the web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2012/05/24 v1.0 My Class]

\PassOptionsToPackage{patch}{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\endinput
```

and the same for your example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{patch}{kvoptions}
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the exact difference of latex's treatment of `\RequirePackage[<put_options_here>]{package}` and `\PassOptionsToPackage{<put_options_here>]{package}`? I don't see why there should be any difference...

Comment: It seems to work, still I'm interested why the difference...

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of `kvoptions` says, on page 12

> • Since 2008/10/18 v3.0 package kvoptions-patch is available. Before option 
>   patch of package kvoptions must be used instead. I think, the solution as 
>   standalone package kvoptions-patch is cleaner and avoids option clashes.

So use

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
```

Comment: still where is the class in the original MWE?

Comment: @egreg It is nice that `kvoptions` has an alternative and thanks for it, but the problem is more general in my opinion.

Comment: @tohecz You have to call *both* packages: it's `kvoptions` that defines `\DeclareVoidOption`.