# Acrobat Reader changes my theme's color

Tags: beamer, color, acrobat

I have a problem visualizing my Beamer presentation with Acrobat Reader 9.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using the PaloAlto theme and when I visualize the presentation in Acrobat on some random frames the structure's theme changes becoming brighter and this is very annoying.

Surfing the web I found a solution that seemed to work for many lucky people having the same problem:

```
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

but unfortunately I wasn't lucky enough and adding that to my document's preamble didn't solved the problem. I tried to visualize the presentation with Evince, Okular and Windows 7 (Acrobat Reader) and all worked fine.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: are you using transparent images in your presentation?

Comment: No, I'm using a standard \includegraphics{myfig.pdf}

Comment: usually, adobe reader does this when it encounters transparency elements such as png.

Comment: It does it at the first slide after the summary and there are no .png files!! Does this mean that I cannot get rid of this boring effect? i have to do the presentation with Acrobat...

Comment: That could be caused by transparency or by RGB-vs-CMYK issues, so the problem probably happens on pages only where you used `\includegraphics{xyz.pdf}`. Could you make that pdf available for inspection? possibly related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem

Comment: also, could you please post which version of `pdflatex` you are running? Just open a command propmt and type `pdflatex -version`

Comment: Here is th shared folder where there are the files. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jwodl9dtkiibpds/zXTHXoEWtY.  You have only to watch at 'prova.tex' and 'prova.pdf'. The slide's content is in italian, I'm sorry but this is for my master degree. All the other files you see in the directory are images for the whole presentation that I've not copied. I've tried to build a MWE. This is the version I'm using: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011).    Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of [\includegraphics{} color problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem). 
A solution for your special case can be found in the comment by Martin Scharrer (so credits should go to him).
In the document you made available via Dropbox, you have the line

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

You need to change it to

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
```

If that gives an option clash, you can instead use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
```

As pointed out by egreg, the `\PassOptionsToPackage` route is for the cases when `xcolor` is loaded by the class or some package and the command should go before `\documentclass{beamer}`

Comment: Why not simply `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}`? The `\PassOptionsToPackage` route is for the cases when `xcolor` is loaded by the class or some package (it should go before `\documentclass`).

Comment: I was getting an option clash and thus simply followed Martin Scharrers comment in the linked question (without, I admit, understanding why the option clash occured).

Comment: The two ways are alternative; why don't you edit your answer to make this clear?

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new and have edited the answer

Comment: I've tried both solutions but neither is perfectly working. The effect is somehow reduced, faded I'd say, but it is still noticeable. For the record \usepackage[cymk]{xcolor} gave me an Option Clash.

Comment: @egreg Some versions of TeXLive2011 invoke Option Clash even in cases there is no clash: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/loading-package-twice-with-requirepackage-causes-option-clash

Comment: Seconding Luigi Tiburzi, neither passing cmyk to xcolor nor using the pdfpageattr command is resolving this issue for me.