# side effect of smartdiagram on beamer frametitle color in a pdf reader

Tags: beamer, color, pdf, frame-title, smartdiagram

When reading the pdf in AR,I have noticed a slight change of the color of frametitle when there is a smart diagram in a frame. In evince, colors are identical.

Here is the mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle 1}
\fbox{\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{1,2,3,4,5}}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle 3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This was compiled with the 2017 version of texlive. Installed last week.

Answer (score 3):

Ok an answer is here

[Acrobat Reader changes my theme's color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/acrobat-reader-changes-my-themes-color/62719)

Adding

```
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

to the preamble of the beamer document removes the side effect in AR. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! It looks like you've got two separate accounts. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).