# Loading a package more than once

Tags: packages

What would happen when you load a package more than once, say via `\usepackage{<package>}` or `\RequirePackage{<package>}`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Will LaTeX ignore the double loading of `geometry`, or are there some problems and repercussions?

Comment: Related: [Loading package twice with `\RequirePackage` causes “option clash”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58244/5764)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, LaTeX won't load `geometry` a second time.

The first lines in the package are

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{geometry}[2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry]
```

and their purpose is not only to announce the package.

Every time LaTeX loads a package, say `foo.sty`, it does an important assignment:

```
\@namedef{ver@foo.sty}{...}
```

where `...` stands for the contents of the optional argument to `\ProvidesPackage`, if present; otherwise it's empty. What's important, though, is that

```
\ver@foo.sty
```

is defined (it's not possible to access directly that macro). Moreover, it stores the options passed to the package in another macro

```
\opt@foo.sty
```

What's the purpose of these macros? When

```
\usepackage[<options>]{foo}
```

is found, LaTeX first checks whether `\ver@foo.sty` is defined. If it isn't, it loads `foo` with the given options. If it is, LaTeX *doesn't* load `foo` and simply checks whether the option list given now is a subset of the option list it finds stored in `\opt@ver.sty`. If it is, LaTeX does nothing; otherwise it raises an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package foo.
```

so the user is warned about the problem.

The *only* package that's allowed to be loaded multiple times is `fontenc`. Of course a package could use the same trick as `fontenc`, but this is strongly discouraged and no package I know of tries this devious behavior.

Some packages that are expected to be called by classes usually have a "setup" command, so that one can change the settings the class may have made without having to load the package with different options, which would be impossible. Examples are `caption` and `geometry`.

Some classes allow passing options to the package they load. For instance, one can say

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
```

in order to pass the `svgnames` option to `xcolor`. When this isn't supported, there's always the possibility of saying, before `\documentclass`,

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}
```

where `<package>` is the package we need to pass the `<options>` to and is loaded by the class.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not possible to access directly that macro" (`\ver@foo.sty`), when `fontenc.sty` does just that?  Or by "directly" do you mean without using `\csname`?

Comment: @AriBrodsky `\ver@foo.sty` can be obtained either with assignments (catcode, lccode or uccode) or with `\csname`. The first method is not fully expandable, the second one is.